# Sometimes protractor tests fail to load application in PhantomJS2

Tags: phantomjs, protractor

Sometimes while running a bunch of spec files, with the below mentioned capabilities in protractor-conf file

- shardTestFiles
- maxInstances: 4

  I find that one tests sometimes fail due to

> [ERROR - 2015-10-20T11:54:07.442Z] Session [443db8f0-7721-11e5-947b-7bec43428a2a] - page.onError - msg: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'angular.isDefined')
>
> [ERROR - 2015-10-20T11:54:07.444Z] Session [443db8f0-7721-11e5-947b-7bec43428a2a] - page.onError - stack:
>     (anonymous function) (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:18)
>
> [ERROR - 2015-10-20T11:54:07.446Z] Session [443db8f0-7721-11e5-947b-7bec43428a2a] - page.onError - msg: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'angular.$$minErr')
>
> [ERROR - 2015-10-20T11:54:07.447Z] Session [443db8f0-7721-11e5-947b-7bec43428a2a] - page.onError - stack:
>     (anonymous function) (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js:8)

Has any of you encountered this/similar behavior using PhantomJS2 ?

I know Phantomjs2 does not support all the platforms at this point, but I am using one that is said to be supported on Ubuntu 14.04